# Azure Synapse error- unable to open data file from ADLSGen2

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics

I'm following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/get-started-analyze-sql-on-demand) from an official Microsoft document. But still getting the following error. I have all the required permissions (shown below) as suggested by the tutorial. I went through tons of online suggestions related to the same error. I also followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/resources-self-help-sql-on-demand?tabs=x80070002#query-fails-because-file-cant-be-opened) suggestion from the Synapse document, but still the same error.

Code:

```
SELECT
    TOP 100 *
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'https://myADLSGen2forSynapse.dfs.core.windows.net/users/NYCTripSmall.parquet',
        FORMAT='PARQUET'
    ) AS [result]
```

**Remarks**:

1. This is my test account (monthly credit of $150) and I am the admin/owner of the entire Azure subscription.
2. The linked tutorial asks for loading the data file to the container but the above code in the tutorial shows the path of storage account. So I uploaded the same data file to both the storage account and its container and tried the script with both paths `https://myADLSGen2forSynapse.dfs.core.windows.net/users/NYCTripSmall` and `https://myContainer@myADLSGen2forSynapse.dfs.core.windows.net/users/NYCTripSmall`

> File 'https://myADLSGen2forSynapse.dfs.core.windows.net/users/NYCTripSmall.parquet' cannot be opened because it does not exist or it is used by another process.

**Question**: What could be the cause of the error and how can we fix the issue?

**My permissions** on the synapse storage account(created by default during the creation of Synapse workdpace):
[image]

**UPDATE** [Manage Acl on the container]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> File 'https://.dfs.core.windows.net/users/NYCTripSmall.parquet' cannot be opened because it does not exist or it is used by another

. This problem usually happens because several reasons:

- Your Microsoft Entra identity doesn't have rights to access the file. you don't have  `Storage blob data contributoer role` on your Microsoft Entra identity.
- Sometimes it's because firewall is blocking access to the file.
- Ensure that no other programs or tasks are currently using or changing the information in the area where you are saving the parquet files.
- In manage access please ensure you have read and execute permission to you on the particular container.
  [image]
  **By default, serverless SQL pool tries to access the file by using your Microsoft Entra identity**.

***With all above percussions I executed it executed successfully:***

[image]

Comment: I just added another screenshot of `Manage Acl` screen of the container. As you can see, I do have that access. Also, I have this option enabled: `Enabled from all networks`. This is my personal test subscription. No one else has access to it.